# Scheduling DTS in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, scheduling, dts

We are moving from SQL Server 2000 to 2008 and currently just migrating our DTS packages without converting them to SSIS. I can't find a way to create scheduled jobs for those DTS packages.  Can somebody help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the [dtsrun utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in a job step of a SQL Agent job.

See: [Running SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages from SQL Server Agent Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx#running_agent)

Comment: That's what I thought.  But it needs the GUID for the package I am trying to schedule.   Where do I find that?  Thanks!!

Comment: You should be able to use the package name with the **/N** option, no?